# Want to run accelerometer in background

Tags: android-asynctask, sensors, android-sensors

I created an app that records accelerometer values and stores them in a file with a simple start stop button. I want this to keep working even when the screen is off until the stop button is pushed what is the best way to do this. I was told asyncTask but was not sure if i should do the whole class.

public class StartAccelerometer extends Activity implements SensorEventListener,OnClickListener 
{

```
private SensorManager SensorManager;
private Sensor Accelerometer;
TextView title,tvx,tvy,tvz;
EditText etshowval;
RelativeLayout layout;
private String acc;
private String read_str = "";
private final String filepath = "/mnt/sdcard/acc.txt";
private BufferedWriter BufferedWriter;
private BufferedReader BufferedReader;
private float x;
private float y;
private float z;

public static final int MSG_DONE = 1;
public static final int MSG_ERROR = 2;
public static final int MSG_STOP = 3;

private boolean running;
private Handler Handler;
private HandlerThread HandlerThread;


Button stop,start;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accelerometer);
    SensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Accelerometer = SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    SensorManager.registerListener(this, Accelerometer, android.hardware.SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  //get layout
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

    //get textviews
    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);   
    tvx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xval);
    tvy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yval);
    tvz = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zval);
    etshowval = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.showval);
    title.setText("Accelerator");

    HandlerThread = new HandlerThread("Working Thread");
    HandlerThread.start();

    Handler = new Handler(HandlerThread.getLooper());
    Handler.post(Run);

    start= (Button) findViewById(R.id.startAccel);
    stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private Runnable Run = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (running)
            {

                try 
                {
                    WriteFile(filepath,acc);

                                      } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                }

            }


            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

public void onClick(View view) 
{
    if(view.getId() == R.id.startAccel){
        start();

    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.button2){
        stop();
    }

}


private synchronized void start()
{
    running = true;
}

private synchronized void stop()
{
    running = false;
}



@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
{
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) 
    {
        x = sensorEvent.values[0]; 
        y = sensorEvent.values[1]; 
        z = sensorEvent.values[2]; 
        acc= String.valueOf(x) + ", " + String.valueOf(y) + ", " + String.valueOf(z);

        tvx.setText("X = "+ String.valueOf(x));
        tvy.setText("Y = "+ String.valueOf(y));
        tvz.setText("Z = "+ String.valueOf(z));
    }
}

public void CreateFile(String path)
{
    File f = new File(path);
    try {
        Log.d("ACTIVITY", "Create a File.");
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String ReadFile (String filepath)
{
    BufferedReader = null;
    String tmp = null;

    if (!FileIsExist(filepath))
        CreateFile(filepath);

    try 
    {
        BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
        // Read string
        while ((tmp = BufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            tmp += "\n";
            read_str += tmp;
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return read_str;
}

public void WriteFile(String filepath, String str)
{
    BufferedWriter = null;

    if (!FileIsExist(filepath))
        CreateFile(filepath);

    try 
    {
        BufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath, true));
        BufferedWriter.write(str);
        BufferedWriter.newLine();
        BufferedWriter.flush();
        BufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean FileIsExist(String filepath)
{
    File f = new File(filepath);

    if (! f.exists())
    {
        Log.e("ACTIVITY", "File does not exist.");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
   // Toast.makeText(this, "Unregister accelerometerListener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //super.onPause();

    super.onPause();
    if (running == true) {
        SensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of activity use Service:

On_start_service --> register the listener.

On_stop_service --> unregister the listener.

Once when u click the start_button start the service and register the sensor , Untill you click the stop_button the accelerometer sensor keeps on listening for sensor value changes . Once if you click the stop_button unregister the listener and get the last updated value and stop the service.

you can manually start and stop the service using

```
startService()
stopService()
```

In the onStart() function you can add the actual functionality to be carried out.

The service keeps on running in the background untill your activity is terminated.

For more information on Services refer http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Okay thank you for the help just wanted to try and clear a few things up. When you say change activity to service are you talking about the xml file or at the top of the main class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a New Service , from the activity when the start_button is clicked register the listener and start the service by calling startService() 
From the activity when the stop_button is clicked unregister the listener and stop the service using stopService().

The service keeps on listening for the sensor changes even if the screen is off and you can record the values of accelerometer.

Declare the Service in the manifest file without fail.